# Is <> SARGable or not? If not, what can I use instead?

Tags: sql

I'll attempt this one more time I guess..

I've seen people saying <> is sargable, <> is not sargable, etc, and sorry, but I want clarification. And what I also want that seems impossible to get is an example of a bad query that uses <> and a more SARGable query that uses a different operator. I've seen examples about how to make a lot of queries SARGable, but no examples that use the <> operator.

I already tried to ask this once and it must be over peoples heads since they thought it wasn't a real question, but it is a real question and I want a real answer, and if I get a real answer then I can look at all of my stored procs and make better decisions on which ones to change.

Thanks..

Comment: What is the difference?  The question you should care about is "Can the engine optimize my query properly?", followed by "How can I tune this query for better performance?"

Comment: I don't think <> is sargable, but even more strongly believe that there is no replacement for the <> operator which is sargable.  So yeah, it is "impossible to get is an example of a bad query that uses <> and a more SARGable query that uses a different operator".

Comment: Ok now that is a pretty good answer, I think, unless someone can actually provide an example. Thank you. I still wonder why you don't 'think' <> is SARGable though, since the point of the question was partly so I could know for sure.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What does the execution plan say?

Comment: SQL server and the point is that I have a lot of stored procs and most of the execution plans at the moment are clustered index seek. A lot of these queries use the <> operator so when I go through and add indexes, I need to know what to change, if anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operator `<>` is SARGable, but depending on what you are comparing it might not help much that it is.

Ref:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

> "Sargable operators that rarely improve performance: <>,IN,OR,NOT IN,
>   NOT EXISTS, NOT LIKE"

An operator like `=` is more likely to give good performance becauce the database can look up a single or a limited number of records from an index. When you use the `<>` operator, the database often has to scan the entire index to get the relevant records.

A query where the database could make some use of an index with the `<>` operator would be if it's a non-unique index, and there are few different values in the column so that many records can be elliminated using the index, not just a single or a few records.

Comment: So this person is wrong?  http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1178/definition-of-sargable.html        I've also seen people say the wikipedia article is wrong..

Comment: @IQtheMC: The operator `<>` definitely is SARGable, as the database can make use of the fact that the index is sorted. In the same way that the database can look up items from the end of the index for the `>` operator, it can look up items from the start and the end of the index for the `<>` operator. However, unless the condition elliminates a lot of records, the database will scan most of the index anyway, so the gain is often very small.

Comment: Sweet, a definite answer with an explanation. Thank you. I think I understand how to proceed with these queries now if you're right, and your explanation makes sense, so I think you are right..

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says it is a Sargable operator that rarely improves performance

> Sargable operators: =,>,<,>=,<=,BETWEEN,LIKE without leading %
>
> Sargable operators that rarely improve performance: <>,IN,OR,NOT IN,
>
> NOT EXISTS, NOT LIKE Non-sargable operators: LIKE with leading %

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: It's hard to know who to believe after seeing this  http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1178/definition-of-sargable.html